# Software timing attack using Kocher method

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, dsa, side-channel-attack

What's the minimum number of random sample points needed in Kocher's timing attack, so that we can determine enough valid measurements of $A_{i,r}$ and $D_{i,r}$?

I'm working from this paper: Volker Müller, [*Experimental Results for Timing Attacks on Elliptic Curve Cryptosystems*](http://lecturer.ukdw.ac.id/vmueller/publications/downloader.php?type=Plain%20Adobe%20PDF&name=timing) (pdf), in Proceedings of the National Seminar on "Penerapan dan Pemanfaatan Mobile Application dalam Dunia Bisnis, Industri dan Pendidikan", Atma Jaya University, Sep. 2003.

There, it is guessed 10 bits of $k$ from $Q=k\times P_i$, but there is no explanation of how many random points $P_i$ he tests.